# Conversion of string constant to numeric value using C

Tags: c, algorithm, debugging, optimization

I have written a C program which uses two different algorithms to convert a string constant representing a numeric value to its integer value. For some reasons, the first algorithm, atoi(),  doesn't execute properly on large values, while the second algorithm, atoi_imp(), works fine. Is this an optimization issue or some other error? The problem is that the first function makes the program's process to terminate with an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned long long int atoi(const char[]);
unsigned long long int atoi_imp(const char[]);

int main(void) {
    printf("%llu\n", atoi("9417820179"));
    printf("%llu\n", atoi_imp("9417820179"));
    return 0;
}

unsigned long long int atoi(const char str[]) {
    unsigned long long int i, j, power, num = 0;
    for (i = strlen(str) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        power = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(str) - i - 1; ++j) {
            power *= 10;
        }
        num += (str[i] - '0') * power;
    }
    return num;
}

unsigned long long int atoi_imp(const char str[]) {
    unsigned long long int i, num = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9'; ++i) {
        num = num * 10 + (str[i] - '0');
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: What does *doesn't execute properly* mean? That's a pretty meaningless phrase as a problem description. What **specific problem** are you having?

Comment: @KenWhite The problem is that the first function makes the program's process to terminate with an error.

Comment: Don't tell me. :-) Instead, [edit] your question and put it there, where people can see it. It's no good buried in comment clutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok there is at least one problem with your function atoi.
You are looping down on an unsigned value and check if its bigger equal zero, which should be an underflow.

The most easy fix is index shifting i.e.:

```
unsigned long long int my_atoi(const char str[]) {
    unsigned long long int i, j, power, num = 0;
    for (i = strlen(str); i != 0; --i) {
        power = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(str) - i; ++j) {
            power *= 10;
        }
        num += (str[i-1] - '0') * power;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: good catch, seems to be the only problem from what I can see.

Comment: Unsigned underflow is not "undefined by the standard". Unsigned calculations are clearly defined and merely wrap. Per [**6.2.5 Types**, paragraph 9](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p9): "a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type."  The problem with the code appears to be an unsigned value is always greater than or equal to zero, so the loop never terminates.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you I wasn't sure how to express it properly I'll edit it out.

Comment: @AndrewHenle the undefined behavior is a result of the underflow. He later tries to access str[i] - which since of i is underflowed is out of bounce.

Comment: You should compute `strlen(str)` just once.

Comment: @NotT90 Again, underflow of an unsigned value is not undefined behavior - unsigned underflow is clearly defined by the C standard.  Undefined behavior has very specific meaning and you need to be careful with using that phrase - the code as originally posted was wrong, but the comparison in question was not undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle ok how to phrase " *i* is underflowing and *str* is only 10 bytes long. Therefore the access of *str[i]* where *i* is bigger than 10 because of said underflow is undefined"? Sorry if my phrasing is weird

Comment: @chqrlie one could do even more improvements - all i wanted was to show that small changes on indices could fix the issue

Answer (score 3):

`atoi` is part of C standard library, with signature `int atoi(const char *);`.

You are declaring that a function with that name exists, but give it different return type. Note that in C, function name is the only thing that matters, and the toolchain can only trust what you tell in the source code. If you lie to the compiler, like here, all bets are off.

You should select different name for your own implementation to avoid issues.

---

As researched by @pmg, C standard (link to [C99.7.1.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.1.3)) says, using names from C standard library for your own global symbols (functions or global variables) is explicitly *Undefined Behavior*. Beware of nasal demons!

Comment: I've reread [C99 7.1.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.1.3) and see you're right. Using your own `atoi()` is UB. Sorry for the confusion, thanks for straightning me out. Previous wrong comments deleted.

Comment: I upvoted. Then changed my mind and downvoted. Then changed my mind again. The reason I'm having a problem with your answer is due to the fact that NotT90's was accepted, indicating to me that the problem was not caused by an attempt to redefine `atoi`. Therefore, your answer, in my opinion should have been only a comment on the OP. But then I changed my mind for two reasons: (1) your advice is good and might be lost in a comment and (2) I lost reputation as a result of downvoting. Not sure why the loss takes place but the stronger reason is #1 and so #2 is a bit irrelevant.

Comment: @jeff6times7 Ah, fair 'nuff. Yeah, I think it's ok to have an answer which indicates a problem in the code, and *could* be the correct answer, even if it turns out to not be the root of the problem asked about.

Answer (score 1):

Too late, but may help.  I did for base 10, in case you change the base you need to take care about how to compute the digit 0, in `*p-'0'`.

I would use the [Horner's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) to compute the value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
  char *a = "5363", *p = a;
  int unsigned base = 10;
  long unsigned x = 0;
  while(*p) {
    x*=base;
    x+=(*p-'0');
    p++;
  }
  printf("%lu\n", x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function has an infinite loop: as `i` is unsigned, `i >= 0` is always true.

It can be improved in different ways:

- you should compute the length of `str` just once. `strlen()` is not cheap, it must scan the string until it finds the null terminator. The compiler is not always capable of optimizing away redundant calls for the same argument.
- `power` could be computed incrementally, avoiding the need for a nested loop.
- you should not use the name `atoi` as it is a standard function in the C library.  Unless you implement its specification exactly and correctly, you should use a different name.

Here is a corrected and improved version:

```
unsigned long long int atoi_power(const char str[]) {
    size_t i, len = strlen(str);
    unsigned long long int power = 1, num = 0;
    for (i = len; i-- > 0; ) {
        num += (str[i] - '0') * power;
        power *= 10;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Modified this way, the function should have a similar performance as the `atoi_imp` version. Note however that they do not implement the same semantics. `atoi_pow` must be given a string of digits, whereas `atoi_imp` can have trailing characters.

As a matter of fact neither `atoi_imp` nor `atoi_pow` implement the specification of `atoi` extended to handle larger unsigned integers:

- `atoi` ignored any leading white space characters,
- `atoi` accepts an optional sign, either `'+'` or `'-'`.
- `atoi` consumes all following decimal digits, the behavior on overflow is undefined.
- `atoi` ignores and trailing characters that are not decimal digits.

Given these semantics, the natural implementation or `atoi` is that of `atoi_imp` with extra tests. Note that even `strtoull()`, which you could use to implement your function handles white space and an optional sign, although the conversion of negative values may give surprising results.